# Relation of Betti numbers to Veneziano's scattering amplitude?

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics

I came across Veneziano's famous formula for the scattering amplitude for four tachyons written as

$$A(s,t)= \sum_{n \geq0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n-1 + \alpha^{'}s}\frac{P_n(\alpha^{'}t)}{n!},\:\:\:\:P_n(x)=\frac{(x-2)!}{(x-n-2)!}$$

(G. Arutyunov, [Lectures on String Theory](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~aruty101/lecture1.pdf), pg. 55) and noted that the polynomial $P_n(x)$ is the generating function for the Betti numbers of smooth Riemann surfaces of genus $0$ with marked points, ${\mathcal{M}}_{0,n+2}$ (R. Murri, [Fatgraph Algorithms and the Homology of the Kontsevich Complex](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1820), pg. 3). Is there any physical relation of the Betti numbers to the physics?

Comment: The original question is on Physics Overflow.

Comment: http://physicsoverflow.org/24003/relation-of-betti-numbers-venezianos-scattering-amplitude